# Intuition behind bound of second moment of Greens function by fractional moment

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, localization, green-function

Consider the Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} = l^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ for some dimension $d$ with basis given by the basisvectors $\{ \vert {x} \rangle \}_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^d} $.
Let $A$ be an either self-adjoint (or unitary) bounded operator on  $ \mathcal{H}$ which is local in the sense that $\langle y \vert A \vert {x} \rangle = 0$ if $x$ and $y$ are further apart than some constant say $2$ in the graph distance on $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Now, if we suppose that $A$ is self-adjoint and has the form $A = S +V$ for some $V$ which is on-site (meaning that $\langle y \vert V \vert {x} \rangle = \delta_{x,y} V(x)$) where $\{ V(x) \}_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^d}$ sufficiently independent.

The Greens function of $A$ is given by $ G(x,y;z) = \langle x \mid (A-z)^{-1} \vert {y} \rangle $ for some $z \not \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, it is proven for example here: http://www.mathphys.org/AZschool/material/AZ10-Stolz.pdf. (Prop 5.1) that for some constant $C_1> 0$ then
\begin{align*} 
\vert \text{Im}(z) \vert \mathbb{E}_x \left( \vert G(x,y;z) \vert^2 \right) \leq C_1 \mathbb{E}_x \left( \vert G(x,y;z) \vert^s \right). 
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{E}_x $ denotes the expectation with respect to the variable $V(x)$.

I understand the proof of this inequality. But what does this bound really mean? And when (i.e. how much independence of $\{ V(x) \}_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^d}$) can  one can expect to have such a bound?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/733130/2451